# mysqli_real_escape_string wont work?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I got this simple search engine code but steal can't prevent it from my SQL Injections

```
 $sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($searchengine,$sql);
```

isn't working or I'm using it wrong... what am i doing wrong?

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("searchengine");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE pagecontent LIKE '%$_GET[term]%' LIMIT 0,$_GET[results]");

while($ser = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { echo "<h2><a href='$ser[pageurl]'>$ser[pageurl]</a></h2>"; }


?>
```

Comment: Choose an extension and stick to it. You cannot mix them. (And the choice is rather clear IMHO.)

Comment: The big red *This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future* warning in the Original MySQL API manual page should be enough reason to stick to MySQLi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysqli_real_escape_string` is part of the `mysqli` module. You are mixing and not using the function properly.

This is how you do it correctly:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("searchengine");

$sql = mysql_query(sprintf(
    "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE pagecontent LIKE '%s' LIMIT 0,%d",
        '%'. mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']) .'%',
        mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['results']))
);

while($ser = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<h2><a href='$ser[pageurl]'>$ser[pageurl]</a></h2>";
}

// don't forget to close connection
mysql_close();
```

P.S. `mysql_*` is officially deprecated. Please look into using `PDO` or `MySQLi` library.

Comment: Your method will fail if the `term` parameter happens to start with a letter recognised by `sprintf`. Literal `%` signs should be doubled up in that funcion.

Comment: ... Of course, it's kind of silly to escape the `term` parameter, but not the `results` parameter...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol the sprintf will cast the `$_GET['results']` as a digit/number because of the format place holder `%d` - so no need to escape that.